# How to address table content like an object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to address the table-formated output of my function like an object, i.e. the row [2] column 'Action' should be addressable like $r[2].Action. How can I do that?

I tried using 'ConvertFrom-SourceTable' from the powershellgallery, but that didn't work. And I'd rather have a simple solution without extra installs.

```
Function Get-NetFirewallRulesByPort {

    Param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateRange(1,65535)]
            [int] $port )

    Get-NetFirewallRule | 
        where { ($_ | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort -eq ${port} } |
        select Enabled, Action, Direction, DisplayName | ft -AutoSize

}

# usage:
$r = (Get-NetFirewallRulesByPort 443)
$r

# required:
Write-Host $r[2].Action
Write-Host $r[1].DisplayName
# etc. ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this `| ft -AutoSize` in your function, you force it to output the gathered data formatted **for display purposes only**

Trying to decode that later to make it an array of objects again is definitively not the way to go.

Remove `| ft -AutoSize` from the function so your variable $r will receive a set of **objects**

If you must, display the result using that `$r` variable in several ways:

```
$r | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

or

```
$r | Out-GridView
```

By keeping it as objects, you can now do what you want, like `$r[2].Action` (provided you have at least 3 objects returned of course..)